# If statement not continuing

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code won't continue after it checks if the variable x is an integer or not. It gives out a ValueError, if x is not an int. How do I make the program ignore this error? I've tried to invert the statement like so:

```
elif x is isinstance(x, int):
```

but then, if I give it an integer, it immediately jumps to the else statement.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.wm_title("InOut")

root.geometry('500x500')

greetings = ["hello", "Hello", "greetings", "Greetings"]


def out(event):

    x = ent.get()
    if x in greetings:
        lr.configure(text=x + ",\n is there\n anything\n I can do\n for you?")
    elif x is isinstance(x, int):
        if int(x) == 0:
            lr.configure(text="This is 0")
        elif int(x) % 2 == 0:
            lr.configure(text="This is a even number")
        elif int(x) % 2 != 0:
            lr.configure(text="This is an odd number")
    elif x is "":
        lr.configure(text="Well")
    else:
        print("Closing")
        root.destroy()


ent = Entry(root)
ent.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NW)
lr = Label(root, text="Output")
lr.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
btn = Button(root, text="Process")
btn.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NW)
btn.bind("<Button-1>", out)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove this x is. Just "isinstance(x, int)". Right now you're asking if x is (True or False), which is always going to return False.

Comment: @James still doesn't work

Comment: Looks like you might be giving it a string rather than an int? If you have to cast it to an int below the if statement, then it wasn't an int in the first place - See my answer

Comment: I also removed the int() and it still doesn't work

Comment: see my answer below. I'm relatively sure your problem is that you shouldn't be using isinstance in the first place. My solution is not to remove int() - that needs to stay there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be trying to see if a string is an integer. Instead of that if statement, I would just use a try/except block:

```
def is_int(x):
    try:
        x = int(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Put that in your code and use it instead of the call to isinstance. As it is now, even if x was an integer, right now you're asking if x is (True or False), which is always going to return False. But if x is a string that could be turned into an integer, then isinstance(x,int) is never going to return True even if x could be converted to an int.

Comment: This is the correct answer, mine and the other address a syntax error, this actually solves OP. +1

Answer (score 3):

The following line is not doing what you think.

```
elif x is isinstance(x, int):
```

`isinstance` is going to return `True`/`False` depending on the data type of `x`.  So the statement `x is isinstance(x, int)` will return false always since it cannot be both an `int` and a `bool`.

You just want:

```
elif isinstance(x, int):
```

Answer (score 2):

isinstance() returns a boolean, so you don't need the extra x is. Go straight to

```
elif isinstance(x, int):
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more, really anything more than "It doesn't work"

Comment: When I input something  it should check if it is an int. If it is it should check if it's an odd or an even number. But for me it doesn't check it, it just jumps right to the else statement, which closes the program

Comment: try adding a print(type(x)) inside the else statement so that you can see if you're using a "5" instead of 5 or something of the sort.

Comment: Oh sorry I'm blind go look at the other answer that is almost definitely what is wrong.

Comment: @birkenspanner `isinstance(x, int)` will check if `x` is an `int`.  It will NOT check if `x` is a string that contains an `int`.  You can check if a string can be represented as an integer by casting it, see James' answer.